# Apply lm to subset of data frame defined by a third column of the frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I've got a data frame containing a vector of x values, a vector of y values, and a vector of IDs:

```
x <- rep(0:3, 3)
y <- runif(12)
ID <- c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4), rep("c", 4))
df <- data.frame(ID=ID, x=x, y=y)
```

I'd like to create a separate lm for the subset of x's and y's sharing the same ID.  The following code gets the job done:

```
a.lm <- lm(x~y, data=subset(df, ID=="a"))
b.lm <- lm(x~y, data=subset(df, ID=="b"))
c.lm <- lm(x~y, data=subset(df, ID=="c"))
```

Except that this is very brittle (future data sets might have different IDs) and un-vectorized.  I'd also like to store all the lms in a single data structure.  There must be an elegant way to do this, but I can't find it.  Any help?

Comment: You could use `rep` like this: `rep(c("a","b","c"),each=4)`. And you could create `data.frame` without polluting global environment by `df<-data.frame(
ID=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=4),
x=rep(0:3,3),
y=runif(12))`

Comment: save 2 more characters by substituting `letters[1:3]` for `c("a","b","c"))`

Comment: @Ben Or with Hmisc: `Cs(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
library(nlme) ## OR library(lme4)
lmList(x~y|ID,data=d)
```

?

Answer (score 10):

Using `base` functions, you can `split` your original dataframe and use `lapply` on that:

```
lapply(split(df,df$ID),function(d) lm(x~y,d))
$a

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
    -0.2334       2.8813  


$b

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
     0.7558       1.8279  


$c

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            y  
      3.451       -7.628
```

Comment: This should be `split(df,df$ID)`. It works that way because `ID` is define in global environment.

Comment: And handy syntax kung-fu: `lapply(split(df, df$ID), lm, formula=x~y)`.

Comment: @Marek Good catch on the ID issue

Answer (score 7):

Use some of the magic in the `plyr` package.  The function `dlply` takes a `data.frame`, splits it, applies a function to each element, and combines it into a `list`.  This is perfect for your application.

```
library(plyr)
#fitList <- dlply(df, .(ID), function(dat)lm(x~y, data=dat))
fitList <- dlply(df, .(ID), lm, formula=x~y) # Edit
```

This creates a list with a model for each subset of ID:

```
str(fitList, max.level=1)

List of 3
 $ a:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ b:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ c:List of 12
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 - attr(*, "split_type")= chr "data.frame"
 - attr(*, "split_labels")='data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
```

This means you can subset the list and work with that.  For example, to get the coefficients for your `lm` model where `ID=="a"`:

```
> coef(fitList$a)
(Intercept)           y 
   3.071854   -3.440928
```

Comment: This works great, but can you help me understand what `dat` is?  I don't get how `data=dat` doesn't throw an object not found error, since I have not defined it, nor what the syntax function(dat) means.  The plyr documentation just passes a function name with no arguments.  Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: I am defining an anonymous function inside the `dlply` call, with a single argument, i.e `dat`.  This means that inside the anonymous function I can refer to `dat`. The effect is that `data=dat` means that each time the function gets called (i.e. for each `ID`) `data` is assigned the current subset that matches `ID`).  The more common usage is `function(x)` but since `x` is already the name of a column, this would have been confusing.

Comment: wouldn't `fitList <- dlply(df, .(ID), lm, formula=x~y)` work?

Comment: @BenBolker You're right.  This works, and is simpler.  I guess I fell into a habit of always using anonymous functions rather than the simpler idiom of passing additional arguments directly.  Answer edited to reflect this.

Comment: It does mean you need to know the order of the arguments, though, so arguably it's a little less transparent than the anonymous function approach.